# I´m not a USA citizen, I use to had permit to work in USA, can i request to SS money back?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, social-security, payment, chargeback

I´m not a USA citizen, I use to have a permit to work in the USA, I paid $10,605 in Social Security, and $2,682 in Medicare taxes, can I request this money back?

Comment: It depends on what immigration status you were in. Most likely you cannot.

Comment: If the correct amount of those taxes was paid, you cannot get any back. If you overpaid SS tax due to working two jobs and exceeding the cap, or (for those with >$200k income) you overpaid/underpaid Additional Medicare Tax, you would reconcile that on your income tax return. Otherwise, those in certain nonimmigrant statuses (e.g. F1, J1) who were nonresident aliens for tax purposes could be exempt from FICA; in that case, if FICA taxes were withheld in error, there is a way to get it refunded.